# Actual implementation of StackForm MSDN recommendation for Compact Framework

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm looking for an actual implementation of StackForm recommendation. It can be a framework, API or any light-weight, Compact Framework-compatible library.

It's not too complex to implement that idea, and I did in the past a couple of times, but I'm friend of not re-inventing wheels and maybe someone or group did an open sourced project implenting a generic *navigation manager* in order to create Compact Framework Forms application using this approach or any other similar to it.

FormStack explained on MSDN:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446546.aspx#netcfuiframework_topic5

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I rewrote the MSDN Form Stack (originally written in 2003) in 2009 using an IoC container.  [Here's the blog entry](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/11/25/RevisitingTheFormStack.aspx).  Not sure what else you're after - both examples provide a basic and generic mechanism for Form navigation.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Sadly I've two limitations: a) I need to work on top of CF2.0 (customer requirement) and b) since it's CF2.0, I can't use this IoC container... That's why I did some other question a day ago or so about IoC on CF2.0 and I found Ninject 1.5 would be the suitable solution. But your sample is a good way of learning how to implement FormStack from MSDN article. Thanks.

Comment: It wasn't the solution at all, but it's a good guide, as I stated before.